# Merging different split files to - JAVA Project

Tags: java

My client sent me the source of a java program in split zip files (8 zip files!) , Because of the limitation in sending one zip file via Email. So now I need to merge all these files together and import them to eclipse and modify some classes.

I checked all these ZIP files, most of them have the same folders and files. Means that I can not Unzip all of them to a folder... Can anyone help me how can I merge all of them together and how can I build the original project?

Comment: and why can't you just all unzip them to the same folder? you may want to try. You may also inform your client there are such services that allow you to share up to gigabytes by mail, you'll just send a link instead of the files.

Comment: Very common to have multiple zip and jar files unpacking into the same folder hierarchy

Comment: Hi clearlight. If I unpacking them by the same hierarchy of files, I am not missing some parts? I am afraid that by overwriting I miss some part of the files.

Comment: @sinaei unless several zip files contain files with exactly the same path and name, that should not be the case

Comment: Hi Stultuske. I know there are some services but because of the situation that we have the internet bandwidth is not so good so sharing gigabytes would take about 1 days in Dropbox!! So it was not possible!

Comment: yes my zip files contains the same path and name.

Comment: @sinaei then either they're not the same project, or the files are identical

Comment: Why not ask the sender how you're supposed to unpack the archive? It's possible the files were split using special software, or using a specific feature of the zip file format, and you need to use the same software to unpack them. Anyway, I'm voting to close this because the question is about general use of software and better suited for the "super user" sister site